# Browser error messages referencing correct typescript file using outFile

Tags: debugging, browser, console, source-maps, typescript1.6

I am using the `outFile` option in the `tsconfig.json` to compile my typescript files into one .js file.
I am generating a source map.
Error messages are **not** referenced to the typescript file though.

Examples:

---

script.ts: `throw 'Error'`
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Compiling (tsc 1.6.2) will generate:
script.js: `throw 'Error`
script.js.map: `{"version":3,"file":"script.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["script.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AACA,MAAM,QAAQ,CAAC"}`

The browser's console (Chrome  47.0.2526.73 m) will display: `Uncaught Error.    script.ts:1`

That's just fine.

---

script.ts: `throw 'Error'`
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "app.js"
  }
}
```

Compiling (tsc 1.6.2) will generate:
app.js: `throw 'Error`
app.js.map: `{"version":3,"file":"app.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["script.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AACA,MAAM,QAAQ,CAAC"}`

The browser's console (Chrome  47.0.2526.73 m) will display: `Uncaught Error.    app.js:1`

It is **app.js** it should be **app.ts**

How can I get the browser to reference error messages to my typescript files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the same version of Chrome browser. However ts compiler version is 1.7.3

Dev tools console is opened.

1 case:

- ts.config

  `{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  }`
- app.ts

  `throw 'some error in my typescript';`
- dev tools console:

  `app.ts:5Uncaught some error in my typescript(anonymous function) @ app.ts:5`

2 case:

- ts.config

  `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "src.js"
  }
  }`
- app.ts

  `throw 'some error in my typescript';`
- dev tools console:

  `app.ts:5Uncaught some error in my typescript(anonymous function) @ app.ts:5`

If a dev tools console is closed, the page is refreshed, then you will open the dev tools console, then you can see the following:

`src.js:4 Uncaught some error in my typescript`

But if you refresh the page again with opened dev tools console, you can see ts file as a source of error.