# Typescript + Electron source maps

Tags: typescript, source-maps

I have a project with Typescript and Electon. I want the console errors referenced to Typescript files, instead of javascript minified files. I read it could be done with source maps.

I see some references like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089753/browser-error-messages-referencing-correct-typescript-file-using-outfile) but I have not achieved my goal.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us more context, like the way you compile your TS?

Comment: @Abel were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this working with the npm module 'source-map-support'.

Install it in your project as follows:

```
npm install --save source-map-support
```

Then require it into your Electron renderer process at the first line of code as follows:

```
require('source-map-support').install();
```

See here for full details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work by enabling both `inlineSourceMap` and `inlineSources` in tsconfig.json.